# Android Studio, Bluetooth configuration issue

Tags: android, bluetooth, nullpointerexception, android-bluetooth

So im  a newbie in android still, but ive been working on an app that basically i want it to communicate with an arduino through bluetooth, but the point here is that when im trying to configure the bluetooth code, i get thrown an error in the logcat, which is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.OutputStream android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.getOutputStream()' on a null object reference"

, and this has really been giving me problems for a week and i cant find a slution, im sure this is not that complicated for an experienced programmer, so id really appreciate if someone helped me fix this.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{

    TextView txtArduino, txtString, txtStringLength, sensorView0;
    Handler bluetoothIn;


    final int handlerState = 0;                      //used to identify handler message
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter=null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;


    // SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // String for MAC address
    private static String address = null;

btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
        checkBTState();

public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Get MAC address from device_list via intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //Get the MAC address from the DeviceListActivty via EXTRA
        address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        //create device and set the MAC address
       //Log.i("ramiro", " FE:85:EE:7F:E7:6B : " + address);
        if(address != null) {
            BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La creacción del Socket fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
        try
        {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try
            {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2)
            {
                //insert code to deal with this
            }
        }}
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
        //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
        mConnectedThread.write("x");
}
```

and here is where the problem is supposed to be:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    //creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn=null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;


        try {

            //Create I/O streams for connection
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }
```

private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

```
    return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
    //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
}
```

}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4dY4.png
here is my logcat after adding e.printstacktrace()

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4dY4.png

Comment: Your `createBluetoothSocket` method. Please show it

Comment: ive added it, thanks

Comment: Are you seeing the `La creacción del Socket fallo` message? Can you add  `e.printStackTrace()` into **all** the `catch` blocks for the Exceptions?

Comment: i cant see that cause whenever i try to run the app, it throws me that error in the logcat, (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.OutputStream android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.getOutputStream()' on a null object reference")                    and i cant even start it.

Comment: ive added e.printStackTrace() as you told me, what does that do?

Comment: What is happening is this... `ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket)` is called. `socket.getOutputStream()` is the error. That `socket` comes from `btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);`, **but** there is an error (which you see from `e.printStackTrace()`, **before** the NullPointerException). You catch the exception there, which keeps the `socket` as a null value.

Comment: and where does it appear? i still cant find it man, it should appear in the logcat?

Comment: You added the print stacktrace method in the catch blocks? Can you [edit] your question to include the latest code as well as the full logcat?

Comment: just added an image of the logcat

Comment: ive added e.printstacktrace in all the catches as you told me

Comment: I think there should be other errors... Anyways, you could try starting over with the official guide. It might be that the device Bluetooth is disabled, or not connected, for example    https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html